# Can't find the ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't find the ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core). I only have ASP.NET Core Web Application and ASP.NET Web Application.(.NET Framework). I won't get the same files when I do these two, and I can't find a way to get the other.

I've already tried installing the SDK and runtime for .NET and everything in the installer.

Comment: Can you write .NET version and our OS?

Comment: I uh, can't find it. where do i find the current version?